# Soap request sending from java

Tags: java, xml, xsd, wsdl

Currently I need to send a message to a url in the below format

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv: "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envolope" xmlns:xsd="http://blabla">
 <soapenv:Header/>
 <soapenv:Body/>
  <xsd:something>
   <!--Optional -->
   <xsd:somemore>kkkkkkk</xsd:somemore>
  </xsd:something>
 </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

I had xml file inside a string how can I fire the request??

Comment: do yo want to send an XML file inside a SOAP Request?

Comment: No xml content is inside a string, that string i wanted to send